# Apparently not able to append a string to another

Tags: string, append, fortran

I have a very simple problem, that I am yet to find an answer to.

Is there any way in which I can append a character (in particular, a white space) to a character that has already been initialized in Fortran?

Apparently

```
CHARACTER(2000) :: result
result = ''
result = result // ' '
```

does not work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Be aware that all strings are filled with trailing blanks (space characters) after their last non-space character. This is very important!

```
'a' // ' ' really produces  'a '
```

but

```
result = result // ' '
```

produces a 2001 character string (you are appending to the whole 2000-character `result` including the trailing blanks), which is then truncated on assignment, so that `result` ends up being the same.

You may want

```
result = trim(result) // ' '
```

but it is also useless, because the string is filled with trailing blanks (spaces) anyway.

It would make sense when you append something non-blank:

```
  character(4) :: str

  str = "a"
  str = trim(str) // "bcd"
  print *, str
end
```

It should print `abcd`.

---

If you want to make the variable larger, you have to use:

```
character(:), allocatable:: result
result = 'a'  !now contains 'a' and has length 1
result = result // 'b' !now contains 'ab' and has length 2
```

It works also with space characters:

```
character(:), allocatable:: result
result = ' '  !now contains ' ' and has length 1
result = result // ' ' !now contains '  ' and has length 2
```

(In old versions of Intel Fortran one had to enable reallocation on assignment for this behaviour.)

Comment: Hi there
Thank you for your answer. It seems that I may have some other compiler related problem, because I found a similar example earlier, but just as before this is the output when i try to initialize any variable without giving it a static size:

    Compiling the source code....
$gfortran demo.f95 -o demo 2>&1
demo.f95:5.14:

character(:),allocatable:: result
1
Error: Syntax error in CHARACTER declaration at (1)
demo.f95:48.10:

result = ''
1
Error: Symbol 'result' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type

Comment: Get a recent release of the compiler. The only supported now are 4.6.4, 4.7.3 and 4.8.0. I recommend the latest 4.8.0 for the allocatable characters. In 4.6 they do not work at all AFAIK.

Comment: But you can do a lot of useful programs even with normal characters, just be sure to realize they have fixed length and are padded with spaces and that you can use the `trim` function.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice. I am going to pick it up tomorrow. Best regards!